# android broadcast receiver

Tags: android, activity, android-broadcastreceiver

как в android запустить  activity из broadcast receiver ?

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто.

1. В момент срабатывания broadcast receiver будет вызван его метод onReceive
2. В этом методе и запускайте актвити обычным способом

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: есть способы передать данные в активность при этом не отображая ее ?

Comment: @evgeniy.se, поясните. Зачем вам активити если её не надо отображать? Используйте сервис.

Comment: сейчас в бродкасте я получаю сообщения (от сервера). я написал интерфейс в котором объявлена одна функиция сообщение пришло. интрерфейс реализует активити. В бродкасте public методом я ининцилизрую объкт интерфеса и при получении сообщения в onReceive() я вызываю метод интерфейса на активности. у меня сейчас стоит задача убрать интерфейс.  я ищу варианты как это делается стандартными способами android.

Comment: @evgeniy.se, ну... Можно реализовать интерфейс в ресивере. Или реализовать вообще в отдельном классе и в активити/ресивере создавать экземпляр этого класса... А вообще лучше будет второй вариант сделать с помощью инъекции зависимостей с помощью Dagger2

Comment: если брать первый случай, я бродкастом отправляю сообщение на активность которой не существует. Что произойдет ?

Comment: Все зависит от реализации. Пока что не очень понятно что и зачем вы делаете